# Two output from neural network and one target

Tags: neural-network, supervised-learning

Is supervised training of a neural network with 2 unknown outputs possible where there is a relation such as y=a.x^b between known parameters (y,x) and unknowns (a,b). here (a,b) are the outputs of network!!!

Comment: This is a very special NNW. I only know NNW with multiplication and addition. Not with "power of". This looks more like math problem and is probably not well placed in SO.

Comment: I don't really see why you need a neural network for this -- can't you just re-express your relation as log y = log a + b log x and then fit your parameters using linear regression ? Also, @RaphMclee is probably right, this is more of a question for stats.SE or math.SE.

Answer (score 1):

The direct consequence of [the universal approximation theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_approximation_theorem) is that **any continous** function from the compact subset of `R^d` onto `k`-dimensional hypercube can be approximated with standard feed forward neural network with given error bound `eps`.

So in simple words - in fact every function can be trained using neural network, which does not mean that in practise any algorithm will actually do this (it is purely existantional proof, which gives no intuition "where to look").

So if your question is "is it possible to train a network that will aproximate my function?" the answer is **yes**, if the question is "is it possible to make neural network represent **exactly** my function" then the answer is **yes, but given a custom activation function**.